# Python reverse geocoding to extract postal code from 'googlemaps'

Tags: python, google-maps, reverse-geocoding, geocoder

I've been trying to reverse geocode a csv of lat and long data to find the postal codes that correspond to the coordinates. I have an API from google and have attempted using pygeocoder, however it fails to recognise an API (see code below).

```
import pandas as pd
from pygeocoder import Geocoder 
import numpy as np



lndn = pd.read_csv(r'my file pathway', sep=',')

results = Geocoder.reverse_geocode(lndn['lat'][0], lndn['lng'][0])
```

Everytime I received and error:

```
GeocoderError: Error REQUEST_DENIED
Query: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?region=&latlng=51.495290%2C-0.166223&sensor=false&bounds=&language=
```

I then used googlemaps package:

```
import googlemaps 
import pandas as pd

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='my API')

lndn = pd.read_csv(r'my file pathway', sep=',')

results = gmaps.reverse_geocode((lndn['lat'][0], lndn['lng'][0]))

results
```

This worked, however just printed all the info i.e.

```
[{u'address_components': [{u'long_name': u'35',
    u'short_name': u'35',
    u'types': [u'street_number']},
   {u'long_name': u'Walton Street',
    u'short_name': u'Walton St',
    u'types': [u'route']},
   {u'long_name': u'Chelsea',
    u'short_name': u'Chelsea',
    u'types': [u'neighborhood', u'political']},
   {u'long_name': u'London',
    u'short_name': u'London',
    u'types': [u'postal_town']},
   {u'long_name': u'Greater London',
    u'short_name': u'Greater London',
    u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2', u'political']},
   {u'long_name': u'England', etc............
```

I can see that the postal code is in there. Is there a way to extract and print JUST the postal code from all this?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind using libraries...

> ```
> import json, ast
> x = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(vals))
>
> for i in x:
>     print(i)
> ```

This will print out a dictionary without the unicode 'u' of all the values.